# Ubuntu 18.04 cannot boot after installing the NVIDIA driver

Tags: drivers, nvidia

I tried to install Nvidia driver on my Alienware 17 R4 laptop with GTX 1070. However, I cannot boot the computer and it always stuck on a purple screen before logging in. What I can do is just to log in single user mode and remove the driver.

I have tried several versions, including 410.78, 410.93, 390. I am really grateful if someone can help me.

Comment: Try recovery mode.

Comment: I tried, but it doesn't work. It still stuck.

Comment: How did you install NVIDIA driver, from the GUI Additional Drivers or some other method?

Comment: Disable Secure Boot.

Answer (score 2):

**Try removing NVIDIA by booting into live USB/DVD.**

- Boot from live DVD or USB drive (installation DVD/USB) and choose "Try Ubuntu".
- Mount the partition your Ubuntu Installation is on. If you are not sure which it is, launch GParted (included in the Live CD)

  or. Open a terminal (Ctrl+Alt+T) and use the following command:

  ```
  sudo fdisk -l
  ```

  and find out. It is usually a EXT4 Partition. Replace the XX with the drive letter, and partition number, for example: sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt.

  ```
  sudo mount /dev/sdXX /mnt
  sudo mount /dev/sdXY /mnt/boot   #if separate boot partition
  ```

  Note : sdX = disk | sdXX = system partition | sdXY = boot partition
- Now bind the directories that are needed to access and detect other operating systems.

  ```
  sudo mount --bind /dev /mnt/dev &&
  sudo mount --bind /dev/pts /mnt/dev/pts &&
  sudo mount --bind /proc /mnt/proc &&
  sudo mount --bind /sys /mnt/sys
  ```
- Now chroot.

  ```
  sudo chroot /mnt
  ```
- Now remove NVIDIA

  ```
  apt remove --purge nvidia-*
  apt install ubuntu-desktop
  echo 'nouveau' | tee -a /etc/modules
  apt install ubuntu-desktop
  ```
- If network problem

  ```
  echo "nameserver 8.8.8.8" >/etc/resolv.conf
  ```
- Now unmount as follows

  ```
  exit &&
  sudo umount /mnt/sys &&
  sudo umount /mnt/proc &&
  sudo umount /mnt/dev/pts &&
  sudo umount /mnt/dev &&
  sudo umount /mnt
  ```
- Shut down and turn on your computer again without installation DVD/USB.