# "ACPI Errors" and "Initramfs unpacking failed" at boot

Tags: boot, dual-boot, acpi, initramfs

I have a dual boot system. I tried to install Nvidia driver on Ubuntu 20.04 through `sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall` , but after rebooting, I got stuck at the black boot screen, even without being able to enter the console mode. Then I purged the Nvidia driver using the solution provided in this post: [Ubuntu 18.04 cannot boot after installing the NVIDIA driver](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1107092/ubuntu-18-04-cannot-boot-after-installing-the-nvidia-driver). Then Ubuntu booted in rescue mode and apparently without loading any driver (I couldn't connect to wifi using either `nmcli` or `nmtui`. Moreover, execution of `lsmode` encountered an error). Finally, I succeeded to resolve the problems by booting into Ubuntu live USB, downloading the latest kernel (v5.12-rc8), rebooting into rescue mode, and installing the downloaded kernel(`sudo dpkg -i *.deb`). Now I can login to the system and everything is normal except for two issues:

1. As I have provided a screenshot of my boot screen below, three ACPI errors and also `initramfs unpacking failed` message appear for a while at the boot time, and then booting process continues normally. How can I resolve these errors?

   [image]
2. Software & Updates doesn't run at the startup as before. Is it related to the kernel that I have installed?

Comment: Uninstalling the *correctly* installed Nvidia driver was a mistake and what came after isn't much better. It was a matter of DISABLING SECURE BOOT IN UEFI, that's all. Now, although correctable as it is, the faster solution is a complete reinstall of Ubuntu while enabling the installation of third-party drivers, etc. (automatically installs Nvidia drivers) after DISABLING SECURE BOOT IN UEFI!

Comment: @ChanganAuto. Thanks for your comment. Secure boot was already disabled. I disabled it a long time ago,  before installing ubuntu. I've compiled many scientific tools on my system, so I prefer a solution that doesn't need reinstalling Ubuntu.

Comment: Reinstalling by choosing "something else", selecting the previous partitions and NOT ticking format looses nothing.

Comment: @ChanganAuto. Thanks for your advice.